# ContentNegotiation: How to serve other than the highest ranking type from accept header

Tags: java, spring, jena, content-negotiation

I have this Spring Java Configuration with several custom HttpMessageConverters:

```
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorParameter(true).
            ignoreAcceptHeader(false).
            useJaf(true).
            defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT__HTML).
            mediaType("rdf", MediaTypes.RDFXML);
}
```

If I query this setup with Jena I get an error:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers

Jena sends a request with this Accept header:

> Accept:
>   text/turtle,application/n-triples;q=0.9,application/rdf+xml;q=0.8,application/xml;q=0.7,*/*;q=0.5

To my understanding, `application/rdf+xml`, should be returned by the config above. This works perfectly as long as the type with the highest value is configured. Why doesn't Spring fall back to the 0.8-valued `application/rdf+xml`, because `text/turtle` and `application/n-triples` are not available?

Is there an option to activate that?

Comment: You might be interested in [Serving RDF representation of Java model with Spring MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17313801/1281433).  (I'm not sure whether it answers your question or not, but it's certainly related.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve this either through defining different MVC handlers, or by reflecting on the content-type and then deciding what to return.

**Defining Different Handlers**

If you specify a `@RequestMapping` that `produces` some value, then that will be the type on your `Content-Type` header regardless of the automatic negotiation that lead your request there. You can 'force' requests to those handlers by being the only ones available to answer. I use this to return a more-specific type, but I suspect that you can also use it in order to return a more generic one as well.

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/sparql/service", produces={"application/rdf+xml;charset=utf-8", MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody String serviceDescriptionAsRdfXml()
{
    return null; // something here
}

@RequestMapping( value="/sparql/service", produces={"text/turtle;charset=utf-8"} )
public @ResponseBody String serviceDescriptionAsTurtle( final HttpServletRequest request )
{
    return null; // something here
}
```

**Reflecting on the Content-Type**

To reflect on the type coming in, and produce something more generic, then you can actually retrieve a list of [`MediaType`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) objects as part of your request, then use a [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) to define what the `Content-Type` will be for your result. This requires a little more thought.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sparql/query", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> queryViaGet(@RequestHeader(value="Accept") final List<MediaType> contentTypes)
{
    MediaType.sortBySpecificityAndQuality(contentTypes);

    // Do some stuff to select your content type and generate your response
    final String results = null;
    final MediaType desiredType = null;

    // Create your REST response
    final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(desiredType);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(results, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this comes closest to what I would like to achieve. If Spring does not show the expected behaviour out of the box I can implement the decision on Content-Type myself as shown in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

[ContentNegotiationConfigurer.mediaType(String,MediaType)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html#mediaType%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.http.MediaType%29) applies to the request parsing and defines a mapping from the extension to the media type - if the request does not define explicit media type in the form of the `Accept` header but the request path ends with the specified extension that the specified media type is assumed.

Basically, `ContentNegotiationConfigurer` enriches (or modifies) the request data, but does not select the actual response type.

What you need is a controller that can produce either multiple media types or a multiple controllers (or multiple methods in the same controller) that produce different media types, `application/rdf+xml` being one of them. Spring will select that controller automatically if the `application/rdf+xml` is the highest common media type between the (possible enriched or modified) `Accept` header in the request and what your controller can actually produce.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I already have a Controller producing application/rdf+xml and it works fine. My problem is that the controller is not selected for the Accept Header shown above. It even works if I change rdf+xml to 0.9 and turtle etc. to 0.8. But I would like to have a clean solution that works with Jena's default requests as this should be available publicly.

Comment: Do you mean that you have both "turtle" and "rdf" controllers, but want to force-select "rdf" controller when `Accept` header prefers "turtle"?

Comment: No I only have an rdf controller producing rdf/xml. Of course I could easily produce turtle, too. But I would like to make Spring map that request to rdf instead of building a controller(-method/HttpMessageConverter or Mapping) for each RDF serialization.

Comment: Now as a workaround I implemented RDF/Turtle as an additional output format in my RDFXML-HttpMessageConverter. Now Jena can retrieve RDF from the application - although I do not consider that solution as very elegant.